# Which assembly reference do I need for Cascading_ddlEntities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am following a tutorial which seems to be the best solution (after searching all day). The author doesn't include any namespace references. What do I need for the Cascading_ddlEntities to be recognized and not underlined as an error?

I'm trying to create a cascading drop down list in asp.net Mvc for my web app. I am quite new to programming.

```
public class PartsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Cascading_ddlEntities entities = new Cascading_ddlEntities();
            CascadingModel model = new CascadingModel();
            foreach (var country in entities.Area)
            {
                model.Area.Add(new SelectedListItem { Text = Area.AreaName, Value = Area.Id.ToString() })
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Tutorial: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Cascading-Dependent-DropDownLists-without-jQuery-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: It says 'The type or namespace name 'Cascading_ddlEntities' could not be found'

Comment: cascading_ddlentities seems to be a entity framework context class using database first approach, refer this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_database_first_approach.htm

Comment: I will work through the tutorial, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I had the project let me post complete class code here

```
namespace Cascading_DropDownList_Entity_MVC
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Cascading_ddlEntities : DbContext
    {
        public Cascading_ddlEntities()
            : base("name=Cascading_ddlEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Cascading_ddlEntities**  is an entry point to the database and it is generated using VS. You need to understand Entity framework before you look into this code. EF is a ORM(Object Relation Mapping) used in this project.